# Can benzyne be trapped inside a polycyclic hydrocarbon?

Tags: hydrocarbons, supramolecular-chemistry

I came across an article in my organic chemistry textbook, which told about how benzyne was trapped within a molecular container and stabilized for short periods of time before undergoing a Diels-Alder reaction with the molecular container.

Obviously the container molecule must have had double bonds, which caused the powerful dienophile benzyne to react with it. While thinking about fully saturated molecular containers, **dodecahedrane** came into my mind:

[image]

The volume enclosed inside a dodecahedrane molecule was found to be approximately $2.8 \times 10^7 \text{pm}^3$. If I approximate the dodecahedrane to be a sphere, I get the diameter of the dodecahedrane to be approximately $5970 \text{pm}$.

Benzyne was conveniently prepared by diazotizing *o*-anthranilate, followed by heating simultaneously removes both $\ce{N2}$ and $\ce{CO2}$, and creating the benzyne molecule:

[image]

I am unsure on exactly how to find how much transverse space an anthranilate ion would occupy when stuffed into a dodecahedrane, but benzene itself is $496 \text{pm}$ wide, so I can suspect anthranilate maybe a bit wider, but nontheless can easily fit inside dodecahedrane.

And another advantage is, since both $\ce{N2}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ are linear molecules, they can easily escape through the pentagonal faces, leaving the benzyne trapped inside.

**Edit:** I made a mistake in calculating the diameter of the dodecahedrane. I now get it as $377 \text{pm}$, which is slightly smaller than a benzene ring width, so this compound won't work.  Still if we used bigger molecule, it could fit in. **Can this be done? Will this work? Are there any complications involved?**

Comment: All this calculation, and you could find out it's too small just by counting bonds.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying @Mithoron.

Comment: Dodecahedrane is way too small to contain anything.

Comment: I'm also not sure how you did your calculation for the diameter. Did you square root instead of cube root? $V = 4\pi r^3/3$

Comment: @orthocresol, whoops, that's my mistake. I used $πr^2$ instead of $\frac{4}{3}πr^3$. Time to learn the difference between circles and spheres.

Comment: So, this question can be deleted I guess.

Comment: Happens to the best of us.

Comment: @orthocresol, should I delete this question or keep it for future readers? (though I doubt anyone would think of a crazy idea like this)

Comment: Well, it's still better then most questions. Maybe you could change this to asking what molecule it would fit?

Comment: @Mithoron Ahh that's a nice idea, but with all these calculations done, we could simply just plug the values of diameter or width of other molecules and see if it's shorter than the diameter of dodecahedrane. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Actually it can contain He https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedrane#Encapsulating_atoms

Comment: @Mithoron OK, I stand corrected.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I guess it's one of smallest things which could be trapped though, so _almost_ anything would be too big ;)

Comment: @Mithoron Yeah, I'm of the same opinion.

Comment: @Mithoron Yup I just saw a YouTube video about it. Helium barely fits inside it. They called it "The world's smallest Helium Balloon".